# how to remove part of scale to show more in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I am working on ggplot2, here is my sample data,

```
type <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F")
point <- c(3,5,8,6,100,9)
data <- data.frame(type, point)

ggplot(data, aes(x=type, y=point, fill="type")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(data=data, aes(label=paste(type,"-",point)))
```

[image]

As you can see, the `E` bar is too high, so I want to remove y axis from 15-95, so I can see the difference of other lower types.

I know there are some thing like scale free x or y in `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`, anything like these in a simgle plot like mine?

Comment: are there a way to do so by not changing y-axis?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT TO ADD FORMATTING**

Does this work for you?

```
library(scales)
ggplot(data, aes(x=type, y=point, fill="type")) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
geom_text(data=data, aes(label=paste(type,"-",point))) + 
scale_y_log10(labels = comma)
```

**EDIT 2**

**OR**

If you don't want commas...

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=type, y=point, fill="type")) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
geom_text(data=data, aes(label=paste(type,"-",point))) + 
scale_y_log10(labels =  format_format(scientific = FALSE))
```

Comment: this is working, great, but in my real data, the y-axis become something like 1e+07, 1e+15, how to change these to 10000, 50000 etc?

Comment: There is a library called "scales" that will help.  I've edited my response.

Comment: are there a way to do so by not changing y-axis?

Comment: Changing the scale of the axis  is the way that I've seen this in plots. I guess you could take the log of the data itself and put that in the legend.